# Paginated connection plus added edge from mutation

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish what seems to be a pretty standard pattern when doing a `RANGE_ADD` mutation.

Say on page load I pull in and render a connection `chatmessages` with `first: 10` pagination. I now do a `AddMessageMutation` which does a prepend to the that same connection. Since the connection is paginated by `first: 10` the last item of the connection is now gone to give room for my new edge and is thus removed from rendering. I can of course add +1 to `first` on the `onSuccess` of the mutation, but this often leaves a weird flickering effect of removing and reinserting the edge at the end.

This problem seem to get even more difficult if I want to do an optimistic update to the connection since there is no `onOptimistic` callback.

Since this seems like a pretty common pattern I figured I'd ask if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Referenced in issue:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/384

Comment: To clarify, after the mutation to add a message you'd like to display all the previous messages plus the new one, correct? In that case `setVariables()` with count + 1 seems reasonable. Which "end" flickers? Are you specifying a `key` property so that React doesn't remove items from the list?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you're incrementing the count in the `onSuccess` handler (ie. after the server has responded) when what you want to do is to increment it in tandem with the optimistic mutation (ie. right away).

Try this:

```js
_handleMessageCreated() {
  Relay.Store.update(new AddMessageMutation(
    {/* ... */},
    {onFailure: () => this._handleMessageCreationRollback()}
  );
  // Optimistically increment the count
  this.props.relay.setVariables({
    numMessagesToShow: this.props.relay.variables.numMessagesToShow + 1,
  });
}
_handleMessageCreationRollback() {
 this.props.relay.setVariables({
    numMessagesToShow: this.props.relay.variables.numMessagesToShow - 1,
  });
}
```

See also: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/135#issuecomment-134400856